# Understanding Controller and Service interaction

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

With AngularJS, I'm trying to implement a simple service that returns a list of `clients` from a REST service which is then available in a controller.

I am stuck in figuring out how to properly pass data to the controller. Below is my service and it pulls the data just fine. I've verified that the data is there

```
app.service('clientsService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var serviceBase = 'http://localhost:56879/api/';

    this.getClients = function () {

        return $http.get(serviceBase + 'clients').then(function (results) {
            console.log(results.data);
            return results.data;
        });
    };
}]);
```

Next I attempt to use this in a controller

```
app.controller('clientsController', ['$scope', 'clientsService', function ($scope, clientsService) {
    this.clients = clientsService.getClients();

    console.log(this.clients);
}]);
```

In this controller, `this.clients` doesn't contain the data, it just contains a *try-catch* block

```
Object {then: function, catch: function, finally: function}
catch: function (a){return this.then(null,
finally: function (a){function b(a,c){var d=e();c?d.resolve(a):d.reject(a);return d.promise}function d(e,g){var f=null;try{f=(a||c)()}catch(h){return b(h,!1)}return f&&P(f.then)?f.then(function(){return b(e,g)},function(a){return b(a,!1)}):b(e,g)}return this.then(function(a){return d(a,!0)},function(a){return d(a,!1)})}
then: function (b,g,h){var m=e(),u=function(d){try{m.resolve((P(b)?b:c)(d))}catch(e){m.reject(e),a(e)}},F=function(b){try{m.resolve((P(g)?g:d)(b))}catch(c){m.reject(c),a(c)}},v=function(b){try{m.notify((P(h)?h:c)(b))}catch(d){a(d)}};f?f.push([u,F,v]):k.then(u,F,v);return m.promise}
__proto__: Object
```

I can't understand quite yet what it is that I've done incorrectly to actually pass data from the service to the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `getClients` method returns a [`promise`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api), not data. The promise resolves to return the data in the callback. The methods that you are seeing in the console is of that of the promise object returned by the service method. So you should register a callback to `then` method of the promise:-

```
 var _that = this;
 clientsService.getClients().then(function(data) { //Runs when promise is resolved
   _that.clients = data;
 }).catch(function(){ //<-- Runs if the promise is rejected 

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the ngResource service which is really easy to use. It is based on $http but with a little more abstraction :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource